# MPEG-DASH server mpd base url

Tags: mpeg-dash

I am trying to implement DASH player in my local machine which is both server and client. I put the mpd and the dataset in the local host.How should I change the base url of mpd?

Comment: Some more explaining is needed here: how are you implementing this? Why are you setting base url of mpd? What is mpd? Which "local host"? And finally: how does this relate to programming?

Comment: I want to implement the server and client both in my system.For that i need to change the url for the mpd file to be parsed and also the  base url in mpd file for the datasets to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the base url, then the content is retrieved relatively to the MPD location. Which player are you using for playback?